# illustrator cc pathfinder minus front function

Tags: adobe-illustrator, pathfinder, cc-2014

I'd like to know what the difference is between <kbd>click</kbd> on the `Minus Front` option in the Pathfinder palette and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd> keeps the pathfinder operation as a compound path of both original paths. This way, you can re-edit the paths, while still seeing the Pathfinder effect.

Just <kbd>click</kbd> will `Expand` the operation right away, discarding the original shapes in favour of the new one.

Comment: Of note. This behavior is the *exact opposite* in Illustrator CS3 or earlier. Adobe reversed the behavior in Illustrator CS4 forward.

Comment: @Scott So *that's* what was bugging me!